# How to boot into a terminal in arch

Tags: arch-linux, boot, init

I ran `sysctl disable display-manager.service` and rebooted arch thinking it would boot into a terminal.  Now I'm locked out of the machine.

I've tried adding `init=/bin/bash` to the boot options but it doesn't accept any keyboard inputs.

Anyone know how to resolve. Thanks!

Comment: Try `init=/bin/sh`, instead of `/bin/bash`.

Comment: @aviro thanks - did try it, but still no keyboard key presses are being registered.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you ran `systemctl`, not `sysctl`.

Comment: Did you try to switch to a different `tty` with eg. `Ctrl+Alt+F2`?

Comment: @ctx that probably won't help – they're still trying to start the graphical systemd target, but that can't complete because of the disabled display manager. But it's worth a shot!

Comment: From past experience, when encountered similar things, usually my solution was to remove from the kernel command line in `grub` most of the parameters, kepping only the `vmlinuz` file and the `root=` parameters, and then adding `init=/bin/sh`, so eventually the line should seems like `linux /boot/<vmlinuz file> root=<root fs> init=/bin/sh`. Also, if you have bluetooth keyboard, try to connect a USB or serial keyboard instead.

Comment: @ctx I've noted my virtual terminals aren't working - I used `nomodeset` and now they work. However `init=/bin/sh` still doesn't give me a shell that I can type in.

Comment: @aviro - thank you, Yes it could be my USB keyboard as I've had problems getting it to work properly under Arch - I'll try another one.  Could also be the USB hub or something.

Comment: I fixed it, I did a lot of things, and I'm not sure exactly what did it, but I thought I'd list them here to maybe help the next person.  I suspect some conflict with Nvidia graphics driver - causing the screen to not update.  `mkinitcpio -P` listed some missing firmware, which I installed.  I added `usbhid xhci_hcd` to `MODULES`.  In `HOOKS` I moved `keyboard` before `autodetect` and added `kms` - see https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/mkinitcpio.  Also switched to the `nvidia` driver, from the open driver.

Answer (score 1):

> How to boot into a terminal in arch

Run

```
systemctl set-default multi-user.target
```

to start into multi-user mode instead of into graphical mode.

> I've tried adding init=/bin/bash to the boot options but it doesn't accept any keyboard inputs.
>
> > Try init=/bin/sh, instead of /bin/bash
>
> thanks - did try it, but still no keyboard key presses are being registered.

That's a bit strange, because keyboard handling is usually done by the kernel, so you don't have to start any services (unless you've got a bluetooth keyboard or similar), so it should work, right in the shell you get dropped to.

So, the next logical step would be booting from a live Arch image, mounting your broken system's `/` file system into a directory there, bind-mounting `/sys`, `/dev`, `/proc` and `/run` into the corresponding subdirectories of that directory as well, `chroot`ing into your installed system, and then using `systemctl enable display-manager.service` to undo what's been done.
Reboot after.

Comment: Thank you Marcus - I booted into a live Arch image and chrooted and that got me back into Arch.  However, I've noted my virtual terminals aren't working - I used `nomodeset` and now they work.  However `init=/bin/sh` still doesn't give me a shell that I can type in.  It could be my USB keyboard or some root user restriction.  Still trying to work out what the problem is.